# Accessing Meteor production database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, production, database

To check out what's in the (production) database for `blah.meteor.com` I thought we would just do:

```
meteor mongo --url http://blah.meteor.com/
```

But instead I get a URI:

```
mongodb://client:984dae4c-04fb-c8bb-68f6-ed83602435cc@skybreak.member1.mongolayer.com:27017/blah_meteor_com
```

How would I use this URI to access the db?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should use `meteor mongo http://blah.meteor.com`; or even shorter `meteor mongo blah.meteor.com`.

For documentation you can run `meteor help mongo`. Extract from running the help command above:

> Instead of opening a shell, specifying --url (-U) will return a URL
>   suitable for an external program to connect to the database.  For remote
>   databases on deployed applications, the URL is valid for one minute.

So what it's saying is, the url provided by running the command with the `--url` option is for connecting to the database by some external application, i.e. other than `meteor`.

**UPDATE:**

When you connect to MongoDB, you should get a greeting message similar to this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: skybreak.member1.mongolayer.com:27017/userdb_meteor_com
```

Enter the following command: `use userdb_meteor_com` (where **userdb_meteor_com** is taken from the URL in the greeting message above).

To see your collections (usually they refer to collections created in your Meteor app): `show collections`. You should get something like this:

```
system.indexes
system.users
users
```

Now you can run usual commands, e.g.: `db.users.find({});`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am able to connect successfully, but every time I do a query, it is saying that I am unauthorized. I don't remember entering any password. Does meteor setup username & password by default?

Comment: http://meteor.com/blog/2011/12/09/production-database-access-password-protection and here's the original blog post

Comment: or even shorter, you can use: meteor mongo blah

Comment: I get "not authorized for insert on meteor.db.myCollection" when trying to insert using this created URL.. What user/pass do I need for writes? I am trying to insert from the shell.

Comment: The credentials (user/pwd) you get from `meteor mongo -U <app>` expire after about 60min. Is there any way to get or create permanent credentials?

Answer (score 14):

Simplified version of nsmeta's informative answer for the speed scanners out there:

```
$ meteor mongo blah.meteor.com
connecting to: ...
> show collections
    stuff
> db.stuff.find()
    {"_id" : "abcdedghiasdjlahf", stuff: "yeah!" }
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2016:**

The `meteor mongo` command is not working anymore because the blah.meteor.com database is version 3.0 while the `meteor mongo` command is still at version 2.6.7. (on the last version of Meteor, v1.2.1).

Instead, install the mongo cli and run this command :

`` mongo `meteor mongo --url blah.meteor.com | sed 's/mongodb:\/\//-u /' | sed 's/:/ -p /' | sed 's/@/ /'` ``

More details: [Accessing meteor production database in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927199/accessing-meteor-production-database-in-2016)