# Can't find users and other collections in Meteor Production Database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to see which users have signed up for my app. I do the following at my terminal

```
meteor mongo http://www.myapp.com

use myapp_com

show collections
```

all i get is `system.indexes, system.users, and users`

When in fact i have more collections than these.

Also when i do `db.users.find({})`

I don't get any data back, the shell just advances to the next prompt.

What's going on? Is this a permissions thing?

Comment: I think you've [done everything correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801278/accessing-meteor-db-in-prod). A couple hours ago meteor was having some trouble, Meteor.com was down. I wouldn't be surprised if this worked now...

Comment: Hi algorithmicCoder, would you mind posting the answer and closing the question? It would help us to find questions that haven't been answered yet. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Comment from @TimDog copied into answer so it can be accepted:

> I think you've done everything correctly. A couple hours ago meteor was having some trouble, Meteor.com was down. I wouldn't be surprised if this worked now...