# How to check meteor production database

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do I access meteor production database when I have a site called http://blah.meteor.com . I have tried:

> meteor mongo blah.meteor.com

and I get the following error:

> connecting to: sg-mother1-6242.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/blah_meteor_com
>   2016-01-25T17:06:25.430+0200 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
>   exception: login failed

*The above command used to work in 2015 but does not work anymore in 2016.*

Comment: Try this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801278/accessing-meteor-production-database

Comment: See wording marked in italic for the difference between the question asked before and this one. And please try to deploy check your production db now and see if it still works. As I said, it used to work for me as well but now it does not work anymore.

Comment: Such a trivial change does not justify the creation of a new question. if you have information you want to add to your older question, you should edit it.

Comment: I answered on your previous thread stackoverflow.com/questions/34927199/accessing-meteor-production-database-in-2016

Comment: Thanks Ser. I tried and I am able to connect via mongo